# How to incorporate NULL values into case_when?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am working with the following data set.

```
Name   X      Y 
Mike   3.2    3.1
Joe    4.5    1.7
Eric   6.2    2.2
Stan   NA     4.8
```

I am making a new column that creates a new column using `mutate` and `case_when`. The value in the new column is the midpoint between X and y if X is greater than 5, or 3/4 of the distance between X and Y if X is less than or equal to 5, or 20 if the value of x is null. I've tried some code along these lines but haven't had any luck.

```
df <- df %>%
    mutate(NewCol = case_when(X >5 ~ (X+Y)/2,
                              X <= 5 ~ ((X+Y)*3)/4,
                              X = "NA" ~ 20)
```

This is what I ultimately want to end up with:

```
Name   X      Y       NewCol
Mike   3.2    3.1     2.475
Joe    4.5    1.7     4.65
Eric   6.2    2.2     4.2
Stan   NA     4.8     20
```

Comment: `is.na(X) ~ 20`

Comment: @Ronak Shah not having any luck with that, just getting this error ```x Input `..2` must be a vector, not a `formula` object.
ℹ Input `..2` is `is.na ...```

Comment: @rogues77 case for `is.na(X)` should come first. Having `TRUE ~ 20` as the last case work as well (instead of `is.na(X)`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `is.na` to check for `NA` values.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(NewCol = case_when(is.na(X) ~ 20,
                            X >5 ~ (X+Y)/2,
                            X <= 5 ~ ((X+Y)*3)/4))

#  Name   X   Y NewCol
#1 Mike 3.2 3.1  4.725
#2  Joe 4.5 1.7  4.650
#3 Eric 6.2 2.2  4.200
#4 Stan  NA 4.8 20.000
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Name = c("Mike", "Joe", "Eric", "Stan"), X = c(3.2, 
4.5, 6.2, NA), Y = c(3.1, 1.7, 2.2, 4.8)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: is it possible to change this at all so that it is a formula when the initial value is NA? I would like to change it so that if X is equal to NA then the resulting value is X+Y times 2

Comment: Yes you can replace the first line in `case_when` as `is.na(X) ~ (X+ Y) * 2,` but in your post you mentioned that you want it as 20?

Comment: @rogues77 `X` will already be `NA` so why exactly would you like to add `NA` to `Y`?

Comment: @Onyambu yeah please ignore that, that's one of the dumber comments I've ever written